# Logitech scrolling on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, logitech

So I upgraded my Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. But now I cannot scroll anymore with my Logitech MX Master 3. It's connected through the Unified dongle and Solaar. Scrolling works sometimes a litte, most of the time it doesn't.
I also have a MX Master (1) which works flawlessly (as did the MX Master 3 in 20.04). Disabling Solaar makes no difference, removing and adding the mouse to the Unified dongle works for some time.
Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With the installation of Ubuntu Studio 22.04 the Logitech MX 518 mouse scroll stopped working. After some research I installed solaar and lomoco and the scrooll problem was solved.